# How to get parameters from upstream job with out changing its configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I know there is something called "Build after other projects are built" , that we add in the downstream job to get a trigger after the upstream job has been built.

But is there a way to get the upstream job parameters??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), then you may check the "current job parameters" option. This will copy all current job parameters to downstream jobs.

If you are not using any plugin, you may inject the job parameters in an environment file and then retrieve them in a downstream job. I would prefer using a plugin though ;)

Comment: In that case i will be changing the upstream job configuration to inject  job parameters in an environment file. I wanted to avoid that :)